# The VC dimension of hypothesis space H1 is larger than the VC dimension of hypothesis space H2

Tags: statistics, computation-theory

I have read the definition of VC dimension. But I am not clear that if **the VC dimension of hypothesis space H1 is larger than the VC dimension of hypothesis space H2**, then does this indicates that the number of examples required for learning a hypothesis in H1 is smaller than the number of examples required for H2 or the reverse is true.
As I know only that VC dimension is the size of the largest finite subset of X shattered by hypothesis space H. But I don't know the relation of number of samples required from VC dimension.
Please anyone clear me the concept in simple sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If VC dimension of hypothesis space H1 is larger than the VC dimension of hypothesis space H2. Considering an example, VC(circle)  = 3 and VC(triangle)= 7.
We can inspect that circle can shatter upto 3 points and triangle can shatter upto 7 points. Thus, instance points are larger in triangle classifier than circle. So more training example would be needed to learn the classifier in case of triangle. As:

> m=1/2ε * [ln(|H|) + ln(1/δ)]

where m indicates the minimum number of training examples require to learn the classifier. Thus

> |H| for circle is 2^3
>
> |H| for triangle is 2^7

taking there are two classes only.